# How can I call a Lambda function by iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, logging, lambda

I have an iOS Shopping App and want to call a lambda Function for crash dumps. I want to save costs by calling the lambda function without an API Gateway. Is there a possibility to send crash dumps to Lambda by using the iOS SDK of Amazon?

Comment: Hi... please don't re-post the same questions. See: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a library for iOS/AWS. It looks pretty promising: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios